# Change color of slide's text, instantly when the slide appears

Tags: jquery, slick.js

The first time the text is white, and when the next slide appears the color of the text changes when the "fade effect" is done. How can I change it instantly?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmo50w7n/1778/)

```
home_slideshow = $(".slider");

home_slideshow.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    setColor();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beforeChange()` for change directly

```
home_slideshow.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    setColor();
});
```